# How to access a database given a string of its name

Tags: sql, t-sql

Alright so say I have code that looks like this.

```
CREATE Table database_info 
(
    DBName NVARCHAR (MAX)
);

INSERT INTO database_info (DBName)
VALUES ('db1')

SELECT * FROM database_info

DECLARE @temp nvarchar(MAX)
SET @temp = (SELECT DBName FROM database_info where database_info.DBName = 'db1')

--How I want it to work SELECT * FROM @temp
```

Is there any kind of operation I could do on this temporary variable to have the string act as a regular SQL command?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Do you mean "table variable" and not "temporary variable"? Are you trying to get tabular output?

Comment: I guess the full context of the problem I'm working is that basically I'm writing a webpage that displays the contents of a bunch of databases that I'm getting from an already existing database like the database_info. And by temporary variable I mean the variable containing the string, @temp. The output I will be ultimately looking for will be used to populate rows of another table so I don't think the tabular output matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may execute a dynamic sql using `EXEC`. Now, declaring the `@sql` variable would be quite too much in this case, but it is useful when you are not sure of the length of the statement you will pass to it.

```
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @temp
EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: Thanks! This should do it